# How to pause one audio file when another starts playing and viseversa

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have two audio files. I want that if one audio is playing and the user clicks the second-one, the first audio will pause (while maintaining the progress and also continue where it is left when played again) and start the second audio and vice versa.

How can I achieve this functionality?

I'm new to Android media

**Code**

The onClick is in the last if you want to jump directly there also the onClick is implemented in XML , if you want to view the XML please tell me I will update it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MediaPlayer player1, player2;
    SeekBar seekBar1, seekBar2;
    TextView currentTime1, currentTime2;
    TextView remainingTime1, remainingTime2;
    ImageView play1, play2;
    int totalTime1, totalTime2;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // PlayButton    *  The onClick is in the last if you want to jump directly there  *

        play1 = findViewById(R.id.playbtn);
        play2 = findViewById(R.id.playbtn2);

        // TimeLables

        currentTime1 = findViewById(R.id.currentTime1);
        currentTime2 = findViewById(R.id.currentTime2);
        remainingTime1 = findViewById(R.id.totalTime1);
        remainingTime2 = findViewById(R.id.totalTime2);

        // MediaPlayer

        player1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dog_howl);
        player2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dog_bark);
        player1.setLooping(false);
        player1.seekTo(0);
        totalTime1 = player1.getDuration();
        player2.setLooping(false);
        player2.seekTo(0);
        totalTime2 = player2.getDuration();


        //SeekBar *Progress*

        seekBar1 = findViewById(R.id.seekbar1);
        seekBar2 = findViewById(R.id.seekbar2);
        seekBar1.setMax(totalTime1);
        seekBar2.setMax(totalTime2);

        seekBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                player1.seekTo(progress);
                seekBar1.setProgress(progress);

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


            }
        });
        seekBar2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                player2.seekTo(i);
                seekBar2.setProgress(i);


            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


            }
        });


        new Thread(() -> {
            while (player1 != null) {
                try {
                    Message msg = new Message();
                    msg.what = player1.getCurrentPosition();
                    handler1.sendMessage(msg);
                    Thread.sleep(1000000000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {

                }
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(() -> {
            while (player2 != null) {
                try {
                    Message msg = new Message();
                    msg.what = player2.getCurrentPosition();
                    handler2.sendMessage(msg);
                    Thread.sleep(1000000000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {

                }
            }
        }).start();


        // Admob Banner Ad

        MobileAds.initialize(this, initializationStatus -> {
        });

        AdView mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    }

    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    private final Handler handler1 = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
            int currentPosition1 = msg.what;
            //update seekbar
            seekBar1.setProgress(currentPosition1);
            currentTime1.setText(createTimerLable1(seekBar1.getProgress()));
            String totTime1 = createTimerLable1(player1.getDuration());
            remainingTime1.setText(totTime1);

        }
    };
    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    private final Handler handler2 = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
            int currentPosition2 = msg.what;
            //update seekbar
            seekBar2.setProgress(currentPosition2);
            currentTime2.setText(createTimerLable1(seekBar2.getProgress()));
            String totTime2 = createTimerLable2(player2.getDuration());
            remainingTime2.setText(totTime2);

        }
    };

    public String createTimerLable1(int duration) {
        String timerLabel = "";
        int min = duration / 1000 / 60;
        int sec = duration / 1000 % 60;
        timerLabel += min + ":";
        if (sec < 10) timerLabel += "0";
        timerLabel += sec;
        return timerLabel;


    }

    public String createTimerLable2(int duration) {
        String timerLabel = "";
        int min = duration / 1000 / 60;
        int sec = duration / 1000 % 60;
        timerLabel += min + ":";
        if (sec < 10) timerLabel += "0";
        timerLabel += sec;
        return timerLabel;


    }

    public void playBtnClick1(View view) {
        if (!player1.isPlaying()) {
            // Stoping
            player1.start();
            play1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause_circle_filled_24);
        } else {
            // Playing
            player1.pause();
            play1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_circle_filled_24);
        }

    }

    public void playBtnClick2(View view) {
        if (!player2.isPlaying()) {
            // Stoping
            player2.start();
            play2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause_circle_filled_24);
        } else {
            // Playing
            player2.pause();
            play2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_circle_filled_24);
        }

    }

}


// TimeLable issue  * please read the comments for whats happening here *

public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                player2.seekTo(i);
                seekBar2.setProgress(i);
                currentTime2.setText(createTimerLable2(i));


            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this Code:-

```
public void playBtnClick1(View view) {

    if (player2.isPlaying()) {
        player2.pause();
        play2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_circle_filled_24);
    }
    
    if (!player1.isPlaying()) {
        // Stoping
        player1.start();
        play1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause_circle_filled_24);
    } else {
        // Playing
        player1.pause();
        play1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_circle_filled_24);
    }

}

public void playBtnClick2(View view) {

    if (player1.isPlaying()) {
        player1.pause();
        play1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_circle_filled_24);
    }
    
    if (!player2.isPlaying()) {
        // Stoping
        player2.start();
        play2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause_circle_filled_24);
    } else {
        // Playing
        player2.pause();
        play2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_circle_filled_24);
    }

}
```

Comment: hey thanks man it worked  but there is a small issue when the 2 audio ( play2 ) is running and I play the 1st one ( play1) the second one-stop playing but the icon is not changing only manually but not the case with 1st one is if play the second audio while the 1st one is playing it pauses and the icon changes too

Comment: also one last thing can you tell me what wrong is with my currentTime(1 and 2) I'm not able to get the currenTime lable esspecialy on both of this line currentTime1.setText(createTimerLable1(seekBar1.getProgress())); in the handlers

Comment: bro edit code for change icon check again

Comment: I'm sorry i have figured that out but forget to add the comment, but please can u tell me what can be wrong with the currentTimeLable(1 and 2)

Comment: currentTimeLable(1 and 2)  is ok but problem in seekbar

Comment: what is the issue , seek bar is working fine, what could be the issue of seek bar with currentTimeLable

Comment: `currentTime1.setText(createTimerLable1(progress));` add this line seekbar1 `setOnSeekBarChangeListener`, and `currentTime2.setText(createTimerLable1(i));` add this line in seekbar2 `setOnSeekBarChangeListener`

Comment: ok but now when I drag the seek bar then only the currentTime is showing the time but not getting the time along with the seekbar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241744/discussion-between-vasant-raval-and-bhavik-kalsariya).

Comment: hey thanks for the answer, and also can you make a look at this question regarding seek bar and timelable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70999194/12438238

Answer (score 1):

if I got you what you mean your solution is really easy.
when you want to play new one you could stop the Previous.

just use these two method:

```
    player1.start();
    player2.stop();
```

so is player2 starting stop the player1.

Comment: hey thanks for the answer, and also can you make a look at this question regarding seek bar and timelable

Comment: There is no link here Vasant @VasantRaval

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70999194/12438238

Comment: so sorry i forgot to add it

Comment: please check it i have added the link