# Media Player - Seek bar and Time lable is not progressing

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-seekbar

IDK why but after just coping the entier mainactivty.java file from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zCYQBIcePaw&list=PLJ4O8neQ9nvLqkMX4Mk_1ZedTBNCjaPRj&index=1)

IDK why my seek bar and timetable are not showing any progress

there is an exception I have 2 audio files but the video show has only one so I have doubled all the methods also the onClick and a dialog which is different from it

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MediaPlayer player1;
    MediaPlayer player2;
    SeekBar seekBar1;
    SeekBar seekBar2;
    TextView elapsedTimeLable1;
    TextView elapsedTimeLable2;
    TextView remainingTimeLable1;
    TextView remainingTimeLable2;
    ImageView play1;
    ImageView play2;
    int totalTime1;
    int totalTime2;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // PlayButton    *  The ButtonClick is in the last if you want to jump directly there  *

        play1 = findViewById(R.id.playbtn1);
        play2 = findViewById(R.id.playbtn2);

        // TimeLables

        elapsedTimeLable1 = findViewById(R.id.cTime1);
        elapsedTimeLable2 = findViewById(R.id.cTime2);
        remainingTimeLable1 = findViewById(R.id.tTime1);
        remainingTimeLable2 = findViewById(R.id.tTime2);

        // MediaPlayer

        player1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dog_howl);
        player1.setLooping(true);
        player1.seekTo(0);
        totalTime1 = player1.getDuration();
        player2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dog_bark);
        player2.setLooping(true);
        player2.seekTo(0);
        totalTime2 = player2.getDuration();


        //SeekBar

        seekBar1 = findViewById(R.id.seekbar1);
        seekBar2 = findViewById(R.id.seekbar2);
        seekBar1.setMax(totalTime1);
        seekBar2.setMax(totalTime2);

        seekBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress1, boolean fromUser1) {
                if (fromUser1) {
                    player1.seekTo(progress1);
                    seekBar1.setProgress(progress1);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


            }
        });
        seekBar2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress2, boolean fromUser2) {
                if (fromUser2) {
                    player2.seekTo(progress2);
                    seekBar2.setProgress(progress2);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


            }
        });

        // Thread (Update SeekBar & TimeLabel)
        new Thread(() -> {
            while (player1 != null) {
                try {
                    Message msg = new Message();
                    msg.what = player1.getCurrentPosition();
                    handler1.sendMessage(msg);
                    Thread.sleep(1000000000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                }
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(() -> {
            while (player2 != null) {
                try {
                    Message msg = new Message();
                    msg.what = player2.getCurrentPosition();
                    handler2.sendMessage(msg);
                    Thread.sleep(1000000000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                }
            }
        }).start();


        // Admob Banner Ad

        MobileAds.initialize(this, initializationStatus -> {
        });

        AdView mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        // Caution dialog

        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean firstStart = preferences.getBoolean("firstStart", true);
        if (firstStart) {


            showDialog();
        }

    }

    // Caution dialog
    private void showDialog() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Caution!")
                .setMessage("In case you're wearing any kind of headphones please remove it before playing the ' Howl ' audio")
                .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .create().show();
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("firstStart", false);
        editor.apply();
    }


    private  Handler handler1 = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
            int currentPosition1 = msg.what;
            //Update SeekBar
            seekBar1.setProgress(currentPosition1);
            // Update Timelable
            String elapsedTime1 = createTimerLable1(currentPosition1);
            elapsedTimeLable1.setText(elapsedTime1);
            String remainingTime1 = createTimerLable1(totalTime1 - currentPosition1);
            remainingTimeLable1.setText("- " + remainingTime1);

        }
    };
    private  Handler handler2 = new Handler() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
            int currentPosition2 = msg.what;
            // Update SeekBar
            seekBar2.setProgress(currentPosition2);
            // Update Timelable
            String elapsedTime2 = createTimerLable2(currentPosition2);
            elapsedTimeLable2.setText(elapsedTime2);
            String remainingTime2 = createTimerLable2(totalTime2 - currentPosition2);
            remainingTimeLable2.setText("- " + remainingTime2);

        }
    };

    public String createTimerLable1(int duration) {
        String timerLabel1 = "";
        int min = duration / 1000 / 60;
        int sec = duration / 1000 % 60;
        timerLabel1 += min + ":";
        if (sec < 10) timerLabel1 += "0";
        timerLabel1 += sec;
        return timerLabel1;


    }

    public String createTimerLable2(int duration) {
        String timerLabel2 = "";
        int min = duration / 1000 / 60;
        int sec = duration / 1000 % 60;
        timerLabel2 += min + ":";
        if (sec < 10) timerLabel2 += "0";
        timerLabel2 += sec;
        return timerLabel2;


    }

    public void playBtnClick1(View view) {

        if (player2.isPlaying()) {
            player2.pause();
            play2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_circle_filled_24);
        }

        if (!player1.isPlaying()) {
            // Stoping
            player1.start();
            play1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause_circle_filled_24);
        } else {
            // Playing
            player1.pause();
            play1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_circle_filled_24);
        }

    }

    public void playBtnClick2(View view) {

        if (player1.isPlaying()) {
            player1.pause();
            play1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_circle_filled_24);
        }

        if (!player2.isPlaying()) {
            // Stoping
            player2.start();
            play2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause_circle_filled_24);
        } else {
            // Playing
            player2.pause();
            play2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_circle_filled_24);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So well why should threads  sleep 1000000000 milliseconds.
In that case your thread does its tasks every 1000000 seconds.

1000000000 ms => 1000000 sec => 16666 min => 277 hour

So your thread does its task every 277 hours.
The param of sleep is millisecond so put st like 1000(1 second) or something like that which is a lot shorter.
If this wasn't solution let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `Thread.sleep(1000000000)` to `Thread.sleep(1000)` because you just need to update text and seek bar every second

```
 new Thread(() -> {
        while (player1 != null) {
            try {
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.what = player1.getCurrentPosition();
                handler1.sendMessage(msg);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }
    }).start();

 new Thread(() -> {
            while (player2 != null) {
                try {
                    Message msg = new Message();
                    msg.what = player2.getCurrentPosition();
                    handler2.sendMessage(msg);
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                }
            }
        }).start();
```